# Proving without Zorn's Lemma: additive group of the reals is isomorphic to the additive group of the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, axiom-of-choice

> Let $(\mathbb{R},+)$ be the additive group of the reals and $(\mathbb{C},+)$ be the additive group of the complex numbers. Prove that those groups are isomorphic.

I think I got a solution using the fact that the real numbers have a Hamel Basis $B$, then proving that $B\times {0}\cup 0\times B$ is a Hamel basis for the complex numbers and noting that these sets have the same cardinality. However this result relies on Zorn's lemma and is thus not very elementary. Is there a simpler way to get it?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: $\dim(\Bbb{R})=1\neq2=\dim(\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: @DiegoMath: That is not correct in the context here, where both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are being considered as rational vector spaces.

Comment: Well my book (Dugundji's topology is then wrong), also we are not dealing with vector spaces, only with groups. We could also try to prove they aren't isomorphic.

Comment: Why would you try to prove they aren't isomorphic, after you just described a way to prove they are isomorphic?  (Being isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$ implies that they are isomorphic as abelian groups.  Review the definitions to see why.)

Comment: @Zero, the result is certainly not wrong. It is a standard, well-known example of a consequence of Choice.

Comment: @Zero: The result is not wrong, and I don't know what you are referring to. DiegoMath's comment is irrelevant.  Mariano said no, there isn't a simpler way to get it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez sorry if I missinterpreted you man.

Comment: This does lead to the fairly interesting question of whether these two groups are still isomorphic _without_ choice.  (Though presumably one has to be a bit more careful about how exactly one defines the groups...)

Comment: (To answer my own comment-question: no, they're not necessarily.  See, e.g., http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_19_03%2FS1446788700031505a.pdf&code=3275bc464c70c444d990e75cf703ee45 )

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Since the current Question asks about whether the result "relies on Zorn's Lemma" in an essential way, it does raise an issue not resolved by the earlier post. But the article/link you found does clarify this nicely; I encourage you to summarize the link as an Answer here.

Comment: @hardmath: And I think this question should not be marked as duplicate of the other one even though it is related.

Comment: With the new edit (adding "without Zorn's Lemma"), the supposed duplicate no longer answers it.  And this becomes an interesting question.  Answer: no, you cannot prove these groups are isomorphic in mere ZF,  Since the question is closed, I cannot add this as an answer...  This has not appeared in the re-open review queue.

Comment: @hardmath: I don't know whether we're allowed to directly ask specific users like Asaf to help re-open.

Comment: @GEdgar: If you have a substantial insight you'd like to post as an Answer, the Question is now reopened (and I have posted a bounty to encourage such a contribution).

Comment: @hardmath: What more can be added to the accepted answer?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I took GEdgar to mean he would add an answer if the Question were open.  Apart from that, if the OP wants to avoid Zorn's Lemma for the sake of simplicity, some simplified exposition of the Accepted Answer might be useful to future Readers.  It's sort of a nagging suspicion I have that since 1973, someone might have a new take on the insufficiency of ZF without Choice for this isomorphism.

Comment: @hardmath: We know that the existence of such isomorphism implies several "irregularities" (e.g. sets without the Baire property, non-measurable sets, etc.), so once you know that it is consistent that all sets have some regularity properties, it's enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no more elementary argument than going through some form of AC, because the result actually does depend on some amount of choice.  As shown by e.g. C.J. Ash ([see this 1973 J. Australian Math Society paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_19_03%2FS1446788700031505a.pdf&code=680c42651efdb40c1e3a1a9fe14560df)), an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{C},+)$ implies the existence of a non-measurable set of reals.  The paper has the full argument, but the short version is that (assuming that all sets of reals are measurable) one takes an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, defines the sets $S_n=f[\mathbb{R}\oplus[n,n+1)]\cap(0,1)$ (that is, the image of $\mathbb{R}\oplus[n,n+1)$ under $f()$, intersected with the unit interval), and then shows that (a) the $S_n$ partition $(0,1)$ and (b) they all have the same measure.  This is enough to contradict countable additivity.

Answer (score 0):

This two groups are vector spaces over $\mathbf{Q}$, and as these two groups have the same cardinal, any basis (over $\mathbf{Q}$) of one of them has the same cardinal than has any basis (over $\mathbf{Q}$) of the other one. This allows you to show that these two $\mathbf{Q}$-vector spaces are isomorphic as $\mathbf{Q}$-vector spaces. As any such isomorphism is also a group isomorphism, you're done.

Take for instance a Hamel basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$, and a bijection $f : I \to I\coprod I$, then the $\mathbf{Q}$-linear map $F$ defined on basis vectors by $F(e_i)=(e_{f(i)},0)$ or $(0,e_{f(i)})$ claimed that $f(i)$ is in the first copy of $I$ or in the second is an isomorphism from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$, and there is a obvious group isomophism from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{C}$, the one sending $(x,y)$ to $x+iy$...

Comment: So $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: "any basis (over Q) of one of them has the same cardinal than any basis (over Q) of the other one", I think that part is wrong, Rob Arthan pointed out a counterexample

Comment: @Robert Green: the point is that your argument requires the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces to be infinite-dimensional. You didn't mention that important point. "As these two groups have the same cardinal" doesn't cut it. What you have to note is that the groups have the same *uncountable* cardinal, so they must be infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @RobArthan I get your point but your basis seems to not work and also since you put that part just after "and these two groups have the same cardinal", it seemed that the reason why those basis had the same cardinal was that the groups had the same cardinal and both $Q$ and $Q^2$ have the same cardinal, so I thought it was a counterexample

Comment: @Zero: I think you have the Robs and Roberts mixed up. :-)